# Есть ли в Python (или какой-то библиотеке) готовые функции для проверки корректности ввода данных пользователем или проверки данных на допустимость?

Tags: python, input

Есть ли готовые функции, чтобы проверять соответствие типов данных, доменов значений?
Например, вместо базового input() использовать готовую функцию позволяющую ввести...

1. ... только определённые знаки:

   ```
   user_input = my_input ("Ваш ход:", "ab123")
   ```
2. ... или даже заданные списком значения из словаря данных:

   ```
   user_input = my_input ("Ваш ход:", ("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3"))
   ```
3. ... или только знаки немецкого языка:

   ```
   user_input = my_input ("Ваше имя:", DEUTSCH)
   # в константе DEUTSCH, допустим, все эти символы уже перечислены создателями библиотеки
   ```
4. ... или просто указать тип данных и диапазон:

   ```
   user_input = my_input ("Ваше имя:", float, "3.1415926-13.6543")
   ```

и прочие функции по фильтрации ввода пользователем?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+validator&oq=python+validator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4j69i60.55500j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Но Вы можете через `if user_input is / ==`определять дальнейшие действия программы

Comment: Это ясно, по определению. Тут же программисты общаются. ))